# How many solutions $f(x) = 6 \cdot \ln(x^2 + 1) - e^{x}$

Tags: derivatives

For this function how many solutions there are?

$$f(x) = 6 \cdot \ln(x^2 + 1) - e^{x}$$

I  know how to find derivative

$$f'(x) = \frac{12 x}{x^2 + 1} - e^{x}$$

but now what?

Comment: By solutions do you mean zeros?

Comment: You could use numerical methods such as Newton's or bi-section method if you are familiar with those. It has 3 roots: x= -0.353, 0.593, 2.462. I found those graphically.

Comment: @carmichael561  yes

Comment: This is related:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687866/finding-the-intersections-between-y-ex-and-y-x-2-algebraically