# Finding the intersections between $y = e^x$ and $y = x + 2$ algebraically?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, transcendental-equations

In trying to find the intersections between $y = e^x$ and $y = x + 2$ in terms of $x$, I came up with the equation,

$e^x = x + 2$

and subsequently,

$x = \ln(x+2)$.

Beyond that point, I am stumped. I am able to solve the equation numerically using a calculator, Newton's method, etc., but need to solve it algebraically. I have done a good deal of research on how to solve this type of problem, but have been unable to find any problems similar enough to be of help.

Thanks to the StackExchange community for your help. I love your sites and have been happy to find answers to hundreds of my own questions on them.

Comment: There is no closed form unless we use special functions.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I recall running into Lambert functions earlier. Do you mean that I must use functions such as those to solve for $x$, rather than simple algebraic rules?

Comment: Yes. See: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex+-+x+-+2+%3D+0

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help. I was hoping to be able to solve this algebraically, but it seems my calculus professor may have made a mistake by labeling this as a no-calculator problem.

Comment: You could try to expand $e^x$ using Taylor Series for some terms. However, this will give you an approximate solution. A similar (unanswered so far question) is here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686045/how-many-solutions-fx-6-cdot-lnx2-1-ex#comment3441126_1686045

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here again appears the beautiful [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) : rewrite $$e^x=x+2\implies e^{x+2}=e^2(x+2)\implies e^y=e^2 y$$ and the solutions are given by $$x_1=-W\left(-\frac{1}{e^2}\right)-2$$ $$x_2=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{e^2}\right)-2$$ In fact, keep in mind that any equation which can write $A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$ has solutions in terms of Lambert function.

The Wikipedia page gives series approximations.

There is no other closed form to this equation. If you cannot use it, just numerical methods will provide the solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've marked your answer as accepted. While it does not technically answer my question, it does provide the best possible answer to it.