# How many solutions have $ 6 \ln(x^2+1) = e^x $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How many solutions   have $$ 6 \ln(x^2+1) =  e^x $$
I can use there derivatives.

### my try

Let $$ f(x) = 6 \ln(x^2+1) -  e^x $$
$$ f'(x) = \frac{12x}{x^2-1} - e^x $$
I think that it is useful to find there extremes: 
So when $f'(x) = 0$?

$$\frac{12x}{x^2-1} = e^x$$
But I don't know how to solve that using calculus
I have seen [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686045/how-many-solutions-fx-6-cdot-lnx2-1-ex) but there was only link to relative post where was method which wasn't on my lecture.

Comment: Why do you need to find extremes? Aren't you finding solutions?

Comment: I should count solutions, so I thought that I can just check signs in few intervals and from that have number of solutions

Comment: Use inspection with $x=-2,-1,0,1,2,3$. There are three roots (at least).

Comment: @VirtualUser I see... but I don't think solving $f'(x)=0$ is going to be any easier than solving $f(x)=0$ imo.

Comment: How can I solve f(x) = 0?

Comment: "I think that it is useful to find there extremes:"  Why????  Don't lose track of what you are doing.  You want to find how many times the function is zero.  The derivative tells you where the function is increasing or decreasing which will help you determine logically where zeros can and can not occur.  (e.g. If $f'(a) > 0$ and $f(a)>0$ and $f$ is continuous then no zeros can occur for $x > 0$ unless $f'(x) < 0$....)

Comment: "How can I solve f(x) = 0? "  Who said you had to solve it?  You don't.  You just need to find out how many solutions it has.  You don't have to actually find any of them.

Comment: Shouldnt that be $f'(x) = \frac {12x}{x^2 + 1} - e^x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Too long for a comment.*

You are looking for the zero's of 
$$f(x)=6 \ln(x^2+1) -  e^x$$

Since there is no problem with the logarithms, it is the same as looking for the intersections of
$$g(x)=\log \left(6 \log \left(x^2+1\right)\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad h(x)=x$$ Function $g(x)$ has an infinite branch at $x=0$ and $g(x)=g(-x)$ so there is at least two roots.

When $x$ is "large" $f(x)\sim 12\log(x)-e^x$ varies faster; so there will be another one.

**Edit**

@Barry Cipra's comment reveals that I went to fast. If the negative root will always exist, the existence of the other roots depend on the value assigned to the constant in
$$g(x)=\log \left(\color{red}{k} \log \left(x^2+1\right)\right)$$ There will be a double root if, at the same time, $g(x)=x$ and $g'(x)=1$.

The second condition write
$$\frac{2 x}{\left(x^2+1\right) \log \left(x^2+1\right)}=1$$ which cannot solve explicitely. The numerical solution is $x=1.2801$ and, from the first condition,  $k=3.7072$.

So,

- if $k <3.7072$, there is only one root (the negative one)
- if $k=3.7072$, there are a double positive root $x=1.2801$
- if $k>3.7072$, there are two distinct positive roots

**Update**

The second condition consists in finding the zero of function 
$$h(x)={2 x}-{\left(x^2+1\right) \log \left(x^2+1\right)}$$ By inspection, it is clear that the solution is between $1$ and $2$.

We can approximate the function by its simplest $[1,1]$ Padé approximant built at $x=1$ and solve for $x$ the linear equation given by its numerator. Applied to the present case, this would lead to
$$x=\frac{2-\log ^2(2)+\log (2)}{2+\log ^2(2)-\log (2)}\approx 1.23801$$

The first condition write
$$k=\frac{e^x}{\log \left(x^2+1\right)}$$
Replacing gives a nasty expression for $k$ the numerical value of which being $3.71123$.

Comment: What if you replaced the $6$ with a $2$? Would there still be at least two roots?

Comment: @BarryCipra. Very good point, for sure ! The $6$ must be at least $3.7$. Any idea to find the conditions ? Cheers :-(

Comment: Love that explanation - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can see that the function $g(x)=6\ln(1+x^2)-e^x$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}g(x)=\infty$, $g(0)=-1$. By intermediate value theorem, there is a unique negative root of $g$. To investigate positive roots, set $h(x)=6e^{-x}\ln(1+x^2)$ and observe that $h(1)=\frac{6\ln 2}e>1$ and that $h'(x)=6e^{-x}(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}-\ln(1+x^2)).$ We can show for all $c\in (0,1]$,  $\ln(1+c^2)<\frac{2c}{1+c^2}$ holds because mean value theorem implies the existence of $d\in (0,c)$ such that
$$
\frac{\ln(1+c^2)-\ln(1)}c=\frac{2d}{1+d^2}=\frac{2}{\frac1{d}+d}<1 \le\frac{2}{1+c^2}.
$$Thus $h'(c)>0$ on $(0,1]$. On the other hand, $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}-\ln(1+x^2)$ is decreasing on $[1,\infty)$ with $\lim_{x\to\infty } \frac{2x}{1+x^2}-\ln(1+x^2)=-\infty$. By IVP, there is a unique $x_0>1$ such that $h'(x_0)=0$, and  we conclude from the previous observations that $h(x)$ is increasing on $x<x_0$ and decreasing on $(x_0,\infty)$. As was already noted, we have $h(x_0)\ge h(1)>1$, and this in turn implies there are exactly 2 roots of the equation $h(x)=1$, i.e. $g(x)=0$. To sum up, there is one negative root and two positive roots of the equation $g(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange to the form $x=g(x)$ and apply $x_0=1, x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$, iterating to see where it goes:

For example, we take the $\ln$ of both sides and get:

$$x_{n+1}=\ln\bigg[6\ln(x_n^2+1)\bigg]$$
Which leads to $x\approx 2.461953976$ (use a calculator with the $Ans$ function)

Now try rearranging to form a different expression of the form $x=h(x)$, and see where that leads.

Comment: Same idea at the same time ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Haha indeed! (+1)